# Why does the gas station pump keep shutting off mid-refueling?

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank

This is a similar question to [Why does my gas not fill all the way?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5639/why-does-my-gas-not-fill-all-the-way).

I have a 2017 Jeep Grand Cherokee. It seems to depend on the pump I go to, but sometimes I have a lot of trouble getting the pump to keep filling. Most time, I can just squeeze the trigger all the way and the pump will deliver fuel until the tank is filled. Once, actually, the pump failed to shut off and a good bit of fuel spilled out before I reacted. Once recently, I had a great deal of difficulty with the pump shutting off with barely a trickle flowing.

I think I may have two questions here, one related to the pump, and the other related to the filler tube.

First: why there seems to be variability between pumps - some will shut off more readily than others.

Second: during a recent filling, I noticed the sound of fuel backing up in the filler pipe just prior to the pump shutting off (consistent with [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/5645/3646)), which it kept doing repeatedly unless it was flowing at a trickle. My question is why this happens sometimes and not others for the same car? Why would there be a blockage only once in a while? This problem occurred toward the end of a period of sub-zero (Celsius) weather; could there have been ice in the filler tube?

Comment: Have you applied the answers to your problem? ie removed and checked the filler and associated pipes? If not, then you should do...